# create Set object with array in Typescript

Tags: typescript

let say we have an array of string like this:

```js
const strArr = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
```

from that array I want to count unique char in that array with using `new Set()`.
like in Javascript:

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#relation_with_array_objects

```js
let myArray = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']

// Use the regular Set constructor to transform an Array into a Set
let mySet = new Set(myArray)
```

anyone, have suggestion or documentation how to create Set object in Typescript?

Comment: Same as you do in javascript https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAtgngggJwQQxhAvBA2gcgG7LACuIAjDgDQT6EkBMl1BxIAzDgLoCwAULwPT8IAVQDOICGAAWEhCADmRYMgQQAyuAgBjAPYA7UWAREtYHarOSUBgGbmoEZHoiIUaAJZ7LydeF6hIWA1ITD0QAHdfMAAKWFdUAEogA

Comment: yup, when I tried to print that Set object from array. it give me empty Set

Comment: Could you clarify the problem in the question? As for printing set - you need to iterate through its elements https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAtgngggJwQQxhAvBA2gcgG7LACuIAjDgDQT6EkBMl1BxIAzDgLoCwAUKJLADK4DBAB2IAO4RhYABSxEKGAEpevAMYB7MQGctoAHTAtAczmHLQ8CqA

Comment: @DSPdav You can get distinct/unique value from array with below code:

const strArr: any = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
console.log(strArr.filter((x, i, a) => x && a.indexOf(x) === i));